# SUMIF cell criterion

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to sum a range of cells that have the correct date in the column.

The formula I've created is:

`=SUMIF (A3:A200,= L27, G3:G200 )`

A3:A300 being the cell's with the date in them

L27 being a cell with a date in it (in the same format as A3:200)

G3:G200 being the range of cells to add if the date is the same as L27

For some reason I just cannot get this formula to work properly. I know it's something simple that i'm missing. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem I was having. When referencing a cell, you have to use an ampersand with the cell as follows:

```
=SUMIF (A3:A200,"=" &L27, G3:G200 )
```

Hope this helps anyone having the same problem!